# Converts a char to unsigned int - C

Tags: c, ascii

I don't understand the output of this little main :

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     char c = '\336';
     unsigned int u = (unsigned int) c;
     printf("%d\n",u); /* I'm waiting for 222  but no ...*/
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Why is this print like my variable is signed int ? How can I to have the value 222 which I want ?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: First, you should say what is the actual output. Second, `char` could be unsigned and if it has 8-bits (which often does), then 222 won't fit in it.

Comment: So which I can do to have the value 222 ? I try some things but doesn't working

Comment: @Shahbaz: 222 would fit in an unsigned 8-bit `char`, but it wouldn't fit in a signed 8-bit `char`.

Comment: Also, you should use `%u` instead of `%d` if you are providing an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @dreamlax, bad typo! :))

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not specify if char is signed or unsigned by default. So, this is a implementation dependent, and on your machine it seemes it is signed, and '\336' as in this case value -34.

In order to achive what you are expecting, you must:

1. define c as unisgned char
2. use %u specifier in printf.

For further explanations, you may take a look here: [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/char-is-signed-or-unsigned-by-default)